# If-else function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic, conditional-statements

Does Python have an alternative to R's `ifelse` function? That is, one-line replacement for:

```
b = np.random.randn()
i = ''
if b > 0:
    i = 'non-negative'
elif b == 0:
    i = 'zero'
else:
    i = 'negative'
```

So it assigns a value to a variable according to the value of another variable.

Comment: It's not pythonic at all, but you have `i = 'non negative' if b > 0 else 'zero' if b == 0 else 'negative'` - it's frowned upon in Python though and for a good reason - which version is more readable?

Comment: @Barmar Agree. Didn't know the name.